# C++ Passing vector to a sort function does not actually sort it

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a function prototype:

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<float>);
```

and an implementation:

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<float> inputVector)
{
    std::cout << "Executing bubble sort." << std::endl;
    int pass;
    int comparisons;
    float hold;

    for (pass = 1; pass < VECSIZE; pass++)
    {
        for (comparisons = 0; comparisons < VECSIZE - 1; comparisons++)
        {
            if (inputVector[comparisons] > inputVector[VECSIZE + 1])
            {
                hold = inputVector[comparisons];
                inputVector[comparisons] = inputVector[comparisons + 1];
                inputVector[comparisons + 1] = hold;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VECSIZE; i+=10)
    {
        std::cout << "Element " << i << " is " << inputVector[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

It's called from this `main`:

```
#define VECSIZE 1000
int main(void)
{
    std::string fileName = "randFloats.txt";
    std::cout << "Processing " << fileName << "..." << std::endl;
    std::ifstream fileInput(fileName);

    //vector to hold the floats
    std::vector<float> fltVector(VECSIZE);

    if(fileInput.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        int i = 0;
        while(getline(fileInput, line))
        {
            fltVector[i] = (::atof(line.c_str()));
            i++;
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(fltVector);
}
```

Basically, the main function takes a 1000-element-long file of floats, reads it into a vector structure, and sends it to a function to be sorted. It's been far too long since I've done any work with pointers in a language, so when I pass the `std::vector<float>` to the `bubbleSort` function, I'm finding that it's not outputting a sorted vector. How would I pass the vector to the function in order to get it sorted?

Bubble sort is needed here... I'm just doing this for my own purposes to refresh myself with memory management.

Here's an input file for testing:
[1000 Line file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=95AA4016F8BA47FA!18273&authkey=!AG7meWiBoNv4WwI&ithint=file,.txt)

Comment: When you say outputting, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Writing to the console.

Comment: OK, I see. So most of the answers are irrelevant

Comment: Hardcoding the size of a vector kinda defeats its purpose. Use `inputVector.size()` instead.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer - "refreshing yourself with memory management" is simple.  Whatever you new, you delete.  Whatever you new[], you delete[].  That isn't hard at all.  What *is* hard is when you make a mess of it and lose track of where you're supposed to call delete, lose the original value that was returned to you when you call new (i.e. a memory leak), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems. Some of them are:

1. The vector is passed by value, not by reference, so you're modifying the local copy.
2. You're accessing out-of-bounds data: `inputVector[VECSIZE + 1]` does't exist.
3. Use `inputVector.size()` instead of using the `VECSIZE` macro. Ideally, use the `begin()`, `end()` and iterators.
4. There's no need for `VECSIZE` at all. Simply append to the vector in the reading loop:

   ```
   while(getline(fileInput, line)) 
       fltVector.push_back(::atof(line.c_str()));
   ```
5. "It's been far too long since I've done any work with pointers in a language" It's C++, you can do a lot without ever touching a pointer directly :)

Comment: the Vecsize+1 was the thing. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronMcRuer The UB is not your only problem with your sort algorithm.

Comment: @ZacHowland It's the one that matters.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer It is the one that will cause UB ... it is not the problem that "fixes" your sort.  Your entire loop for your sort is wrong.

Comment: The nested loop isn't wrong, it just performs more loops than needed for a bubble sort. I posted an answer below showing one alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the vector to your function by value:

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<float>);
```

Which means you are sorting a copy of the vector, not the actual vector.  You need to change your function signature to

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<float>&);
                                  ^ -- note the pass by reference
```

Another problem you have is that you are invoking Undefined Behavior:

```
if (inputVector[comparisons] > inputVector[VECSIZE + 1])
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ -- accessing an element 2 beyond
```

the size of your array, and you are not swapping the items you are comparing.

I think what you wanted to do is:

```
bool swapped = false;
do
{
    swapped = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < inputVector.size() - 1; ++j)
    {
        if (inputVector[j + 1] > inputVector[j])
        {
            std::swap(inputVector[j + 1], inputVector[j]);
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapped);
```

Notice the problems this fixes:

```
if (inputVector[comparisons] > inputVector[VECSIZE + 1]) // UB
{
    hold = inputVector[comparisons];
    inputVector[comparisons] = inputVector[comparisons + 1]; // not swapping elements you compared!
    inputVector[comparisons + 1] = hold; // same problem as above!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you put the highest element at the end, so there's no need to compare to the end of the array each time:

```
bool swapped = false;
int k = inputVector.size();
do
{
    k--;
    swapped = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        if (inputVector[j] > inputVector[j + 1])
        {
            std::swap(inputVector[j], inputVector[j + 1]);
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapped);
```

Comment: You will have UB when `j == inputVector.size() - 1`.

Comment: Note that k-- occurs before the for loop. The first instance of the for loop will be for(int j = 0; j < ...size -1; j++){ ...

Comment: Ah, doh!  I missed the `k--`.